# Post a tweet automatically from a PHP webservice without userinteraction for multiple twitter accounts

Tags: php, authentication, twitter

I have a requirement for php script which works as below.The Database is having list of some 20 twitterIDs.Webapp should be able to post a tweet on behalf of any of the twitterID given in the list.This happens back-door that means no user interaction will be involved like redirecting to Twitter Authentication page to allow twitterApp to access some stuff and user will accept to allow access.User doesn't know about this back-end operation.

My questions is :

1. Is this possible / feasible ?
2. If possible, how should i approach the development roadmap . My technology is PHP based and involves REST APi integration to a smartphone client.

Looking forward for some deep explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just the twitter IDs to post on their behalf. They will have to authenticate the application first.

This generates two tokens `OAuthToken` and `OAuthTokenSecret`, which can be stored in your database back-end and consequently, be used from your PHP back-end to post on behalf of the user, till the user deauthorizes your application, at which point `OAuthToken` won't function anymore.

Twitter OAuthTokens do **NOT** expire, but the user can revoke your access.

You can implement the above in PHP using one of the [Twitter PHP libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php)

Comment: that means i will have to create one Twitter App. Let each of those 20 twitter A/cs authenticate the mytwitterApp and after authenticating i should store oAuthAccessToken and oAuthTokenSecret into my Database for future use.So for each Twitter A/c its corresponding OAuthToken and Consumer key will not expire until the a/c deauthorize and i can use them whenever the web app wants to post on behalf of these a/c . Do i need to check for revoking the oAuthToken each time i want to post a tweet ?

Comment: The workflow you have in mind is right. You should check the OAuthToken anyway, to handle the case in which the user has deauthorized your application. However, the tokens do not expire over time.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot you both DarkXphenomenon and Chris !!. I am able to achieve this. But though some manual process is involved, i am finally able to get what i have intended.

Answer (score 1):

At some point the user will have to know about it, they will have to authorize your page the first time (you wouldn't want someone to post on your twitter feed without you knowing about it right?).

When they have authorized your page the first time, you can store the OAuth token you receive at the end of the authentication process and use it later on to post tweets, without asking the user to authenticate herself again, for as long as the token is valid.