# How to store and use OAuth tokens in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, oauth

I'm using Abraham's twitteroauth library. I've been trying to store the oauth tokens from the twitter accounts that signed up for my Twitter app in a database and retrieve them in PHP so I can tweet something on all of the accounts. Help?

Thank you!

Comment: Knock knock.. [who's there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536188/post-a-tweet-automatically-from-a-php-webservice-without-userinteraction-for-mul) Why not edit your original question? you've already got some answers there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single `$_SESSION['access_token'];`. If you want to deal with multiple accounts, then you will need to keep (and use) the access token for each of them.

Comment: Do you know how could I store them each in a mysql database and bring it back to this file? Thanks for helping by the way.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd have a table with a composite primary key of username-on-your-site and username-on-twitter and then store all the other data (auth token, secret, etc) in the other columns.